# Rendering mustache template stored in file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mustache

I'm trying in a Rails app to render some json data through a mustache template.

My starting point was this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates

In the cast Rayn does something like

```
$('#target').append Mustache.to_html($('#project_template').html(), json-data)
```

Having in the html a div with id="project_template" that contains the template

```
<script type="text/html" id="project_template">
 ...
</script>
```

However, I'd like to be able to store the mustache template into a file (let's say in app/views/projects/project.mustache) and load it directly in my js.
Something like

```
$('#target').append Mustache.xxxxx(MUSTACHE_FILE, json-data)
```

I have looked around but I cannot find anything that works or any suggestion. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access server-side file in javascript directly, but you can use an alternative way to store template on the server side.

You can store the template in `app/views/projects/project.mustache` for example.

In your project.mustache, you can write:

```
<script type="text/html" id="project_template">
 ...
</script>
```

In your view, you can use:

```
<%= render :file => 'projects/project.mustache' %>
```

And use javascript as same as before.

```
$('#target').append(Mustache.to_html($('#project_template').html(), json-data));
```

I think it isn't perfect, but it should work :)

Comment: That is exactly what the railscast does. I'm looking for a different approach.  Thanks by the way.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I haven't watch the cast because it's a pro cast, or I will not submit this answer. In your question, it seems that you want to get the content of server-side template via javascript, it's far more complicated than this solution :)